# Comparing multiple related and ordered rows within Power Bi

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I have a staff shift dataset in Power BI, where each row is an individual shift record for an individual. Records have personnel ID, start/end times, and whether the shift was a 'special' shift (flag 0 or 1). For each attendance record I want to determine if a 'special' shift was worked within 6 days either side of the current shift. As in the real world, the staff members don't have shifts every single day.
Example - in the simple table below, staff 123456 should flag in the first 3 rows as their 'special' shift was within the 6 day requirement.

| personnel ID | Start Date/time | End date/time | Special shift |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123456 | 06/09 10:00 | 06/09 18:00 | 1 |
| 123456 | 07/09 10:00 | 08/09 18:00 | 0 |
| 123456 | 09/09 12:00 | 09/09 20:00 | 0 |
| 345678 | 06/09 08:00 | 06/09 18:00 | 0 |
| 345678 | 07/09 06:00 | 06/09 14:00 | 0 |
| 345678 | 08/09 10:00 | 06/09 18:00 | 0 |

Any help in how a this problem (or in general a multi row comparison taking into account several criteria to determine which rows to compare) would be very much appreciated - thanks!

I've tried several combinations of ordering the table, filtering, and in-built calculations using times but I'm a bit stumped.

Comment: Did this answer your question? The please toggle the checkmark on the answer to mark issue as solved

Answer (score 0):

You can look for overlapping times in powerquery and mark those

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Start Date/time", type datetime}, {"End date/time", type datetime}}),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"personnel ID"}, {{"data", each 
     let a=_ in  Table.AddColumn(a,"Within6Days",(i)=>
     if  Table.RowCount(Table.SelectRows(a, each [Special shift]=1 and
            (Number.Abs(Duration.Days( [#"Start Date/time"] - i[#"Start Date/time"]) )<=6 or 
            Number.Abs(Duration.Days( [#"Start Date/time"] - i[#"End date/time"]) )<=6 or 
            Number.Abs(Duration.Days( [#"End date/time"]- i[#"End date/time"]) )<=6 )
    )) >0 then 1 else 0)
, type table [personnel ID=nullable number, #"Start Date/time"=nullable datetime, #"End date/time"=nullable datetime, Special shift=nullable number, Within6Days=nullable number]}}),
#"Expanded data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "data", {"Start Date/time", "End date/time", "Special shift", "Within6Days"}, {"Start Date/time", "End date/time", "Special shift", "Within6Days"})
in  #"Expanded data"
```

[image]

Note, above takes into account HOURS, otherwise change to using Date.From() within the duration calculations

```
     (Number.Abs(Duration.Days( Date.From([#"Start Date/time"]) - Date.From(i[#"Start Date/time"])) )<=6 or 
      Number.Abs(Duration.Days( Date.From([#"Start Date/time"]) -Date.From( i[#"End date/time"])) )<=6 or 
      Number.Abs(Duration.Days(Date.From( [#"End date/time"])- Date.From(i[#"End date/time"])) )<=6 )
```